# Getting a string in c++ from user, and displaying it

Tags: c++

how do i do it??

it tried this code:

```
  char num[10];

  printf("Enter num:");

  scanf_s ("%s", &num);

  printf("\n%s \n", num);
```

ignore 'num' please..
i use VS 2013, and my only included library is "stdafx.h"

Comment: 1.) Read a book about C++. 2.) Use C++, not C, if you want to write a C++ program. 3.) Don't use proprietary stuff like `stdafx.h`.

Answer (score 1):

See [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

In C++, don't use `printf`, use [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout).
Don't use `char[]`, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

If you selected the type of the project like console application and compile it as a C++ program then the code can look the following way

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char s[100];

    std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
    std::cin.getline( s, sizeof( s ) );

    std::cout << "You entered \"" << s << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not suggest they should use a `std::string`?

Comment: @NathanOliver It is easy for him to use what he already knows.:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't you use the "string" in c++ instead of the char array. Its easy for operation and maintenance, plus its much more simple and efficient with so many built in algorithms.

```
string num ;// instead of char num[10];
cout<<"Enter num";
cin>>num;
cout<<num;
```

you may use printf or scanf. Thats completely ok